# Reactive programming - running jobs in a cluster

Tags: locking, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I need to run some jobs in a cluster, only one at a time.
Because my team uses Hazelcast, I ended up with a solution based on
Hazelcast [ILock](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/ILock.html) implementation. For the purpose of the question, I am going to make a generalisation about it. Let's suppose we have the following interfaces (that could be easily implemented e.g. by Hazelcast or Reddison (Redis)):

```
public interface MyDistributedLock {

    boolean lock();

    void unlock();

    boolean isLockedByCurrentThread();
}

public interface MyLockDistributedFactory {

    MyDistributedLock getLock(String name);

}
```

And **lock** method waiting if lock cannot be acquired:

```
private Mono<Void> lock(String name, Publisher<?> publisher, MyLockDistributedFactory myLockFactory) {
    // important to release lock on the same thread as
    // it was aquired    
    Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.newSingle(name.toLowerCase());

    return Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just(myLockFactory.getLock(name)))
        publishOn(scheduler)
         .doOnNext(MyDistributedLock::lock)
         .doOnNext(lock -> LOGGER.info("Process acquired lock for resource {}", name))
         .flatMapMany(lock -> Flux.from(publisher))
         .publishOn(scheduler) 
         .doFinally(signalType -> {
              MyDistributedLock lock = myLockFactory.getLock(name);
              if (signalType == SignalType.CANCEL) {
                 // cancel ignores publishOn 
                 scheduler.schedule(() -> { 
                    lock.unlock();
                    LOGGER.info("Process released lock for resource {} due to signal type {}", name, signalType);
                 });
              } else if (lock.isLockedByCurrentThread()) {
                 lock.unlock();
                 LOGGER.info("Process released lock for resource {} due to signal type {}", name, signalType);
              }
          })
          .then();
}
```

And example of some job

```
private Mono<Void> someJobRunEveryOneHourOnEveryNodeInCluster() {
    MyLockDistributedFactory hazelcast = ...;
    return lock("some-job", Flux.just(1,2), hazelcast)
                .repeatWhen(afterOneHour());
}
```

I wonder whether this is a good approach of using Project reactor (and correct implementation) or it should be done in a different way. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a correct approach *when* using Reactor, because you took care of offsetting the blocking portion into a dedicated `Scheduler`/`Thread`.

But I'd say mutually exclusive code like this is not a very good fit for reactive programming in general: you lose one of the key benefits of doing more with less threads, you risk blocking other parts of the application should you forget to `publishOn` a dedicated thread, etc...